# How to set last accordion always open?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Currently, all accordions are toggling on the press. But I would like to set 'personal info' accordion open all the time. Rest other accordions can toggle their behavior. I tried toggle function using hooks but don't know how should I kept single accordion open all time?

```js
export default function Accordion({
  title,
  children,
}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    return (state ? setState(false) : setState(true))
  }
  const childComponent = (
    <View >
      {children}
    </View>
  )
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={toggle}>
        <View>
          <Text >
            {title}
          </Text>          
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {state && childComponent}
    </View>
  )
}



class App extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Accordion
          title='Contacts'>
          <Text >Contact screen will be here</Text>
        </Accordion>
        <Accordion
          title='Document>
          <Text >Document screen will be here</Text>
        </Accordion>
        <Accordion
          title='Personal info'>
          <Text >Personal info screen will be here</Text>
        </Accordion>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: You have to manage toggle for each item, or you can use Index for that

Comment: can you help me how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure with this code, I guess solution will be bit lengthy, but to give an overview of what I am saying, you need to take reference of index which is expanded. Let's say state variable named expandedIndex=0 than you can keep condition for children to display only if current index matched with index available in state.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is receive a prop that would define if it should be open and don't use the `toggle`.

```
export default function Accordion({
  title,
  children,
  alwaysOpened,
}) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      if(alwaysOpened)
          setState(!!alwaysOpened)
  }, [alwaysOpened])

  function toggle() {
    if(!alwaysOpened)
        return (state ? setState(false) : setState(true))
  }

  const childComponent = (
    <View >
      {children}
    </View>
  )
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={toggle}>
        <View>
          <Text >
            {title}
          </Text>          
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {state && childComponent}
    </View>
  )
}
```

And then pass to the `Accordion`you want to always be opened the prop `alwaysOpened`.

```
    <Accordion
      alwaysOpened
      title='Personal info'>
      <Text >Personal info screen will be here</Text>
    </Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultValue` to set the last Accordion always open.
https://v6.mantine.dev/core/accordion/#default-opened-items

```
class App extends React.Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        // Setting a defaultValue
        <Accordion dafaultValue='item-3'>
         <Accordion.Item value="item-1">
           <Accordion.Control>Contacts</Accordion>
           <Accordion.Panel>
           <Text >Contact screen will be here</Text>
           </Accordion.Panel>
         </Accordion.Item>
          
         <Accordion.Item value="item-2">
          <Accordion.Control>Document</Accordion>
          <Accordion.Panel>
          <Text >Document screen will be here</Text>
          </Accordion.Panel>
         </Accordion.Item>

       // This will always be opened as the value is set as similar as defaultValue
        <Accordion.Item value="item-3">
          <Accordion.Control>Personal info</Accordion>
          <Accordion.Panel>
          <Text >Personal info screen will be here</Text>
          </Accordion.Panel>
        </Accordion.Item>
        
        </Accordion>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```